# angular js fails to parse jax-rs response

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, jax-rs

I want my server to send an indicative error to the angular js client.

I saw these examples:

```
Example 7
Project: spice   File: RequestService.java View source code 6 votes vote down vote up
@GET
@Path("date")
@Produces("text/plain")
public Response get(@Context Request request) {
    final Date modificDate = getLastModificationDateFromDatastore();
    final EntityTag entityTag = getEntityTagFromDatastore();
    final ResponseBuilder resp = request.evaluatePreconditions(modificDate,
            entityTag);
    if (resp != null) {
        return resp.build();
    }
    // Build new Response
    final ResponseBuilder responseBuilder = Response.status(200);
    responseBuilder.entity("This is the Entity from " + modificDate);
    responseBuilder.lastModified(modificDate);
    responseBuilder.tag(entityTag);
    return responseBuilder.build();
}
```

and

```
Example 8
Project: zeppelin   File: JsonResponse.java View source code    4 votes vote down vote up
public javax.ws.rs.core.Response build() {
  ResponseBuilder r = javax.ws.rs.core.Response.status(status).entity(this.toString());
  if (cookies != null) {
    for (NewCookie nc : cookies) {
      r.cookie(nc);
    }
  }
  return r.build();
}
```

but when my server code sends:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{

    String error = "RuntimeException: test11";
    logger.error("update voice filed. Error: "+error);

    return Response.serverError().entity(error).build();
}
```

in the client code I cannot find this error message:

```
            $http.put('api/foo', {voice : voice, isAddMode : isAddMode}).then(
                function successCallback(response) {
..
                }, function errorCallback(response) {
                    var responseStr = JSON.stringify(response)
                    console.log(responseStr);
                    deferred.reject(responseStr);
                });
```

I get parsing error, but in general i cannot find the right member in js.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token R in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at fromJson (angular.js:1377)
    at defaultHttpResponseTransform (angular.js:11003)
    at angular.js:11094
    at forEach (angular.js:357)
    at transformData (angular.js:11093)
    at transformResponse (angular.js:11914)
    at processQueue (angular.js:16648)
    at angular.js:16692
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17972)
```

Comment: Angular is trying to parse `RuntimeException: test11` which isn't valid JSON

Answer (score 0):

I had to remove the `"Produces"` annotation on the server side:

```
    @Path("/foo")
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
//    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
```

Then a json object was sent from the server and not just string.